# How to send Push Notifications with custom sounds via the Firebase FCM Console

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

Is it possible to customise notification sounds via the Firebase Console, or Firebase Message Composer? It seems to have a single attribute to Enable/Disable sounds only in Additional options section. If is not possible, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have compiled your app with the sound notification in your app's resource folder
You can then use the [Notification Composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification) to send custom payloads from the Firebase Console, including sound settings in the custom payload as `key`:`value`.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-with-console#about

You can also invoke FCM with cloud functions with this kind of payload

```json
"message":{
  "token":"ewrTK.....",
  "notification":{
     "title":"Breaking News",
     "body":"New news story available."
  },
  "data":{
     "title":"Notification title",
     "body":"Notfication body"
  },
  "apns":{
     "payload":{
        "aps":{
           "sound":"notification.mp3"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DIGI Byte, to clarify, is not possible to customise notifications using the Firebase Console directly, right? I would have to build a server to invoke notification request using similar payload?

Comment: You are able to with the notifications composer https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification  
- you can however read about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-with-console#about

Comment: Updated to reflect your question more.

Comment: Thanks @DIGI Byte, but somewhere I think I am missing. From the Notification composer, the only setting I see for sound is a toggle On/Off, in Advance Options. I would expect to be able to enter the custom sound file name as a string. I can, however, send POST request with custom payloads using FCM cloud functions as you posted above, but that's not what our operations team would like. Thoughts?

Comment: Just above the sound on/off is a key:value from there, If I am reading the documentation correctly, you set the key to 'sound' and the value, as the name or file name of the sound.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks! That's what threw me off. Thanks!

Comment: @DIGIByte Setting a value for the key "sound" in Firebase Console doesn't help to play the specific sound(it plays standard iOS notification sound), but it works when I try with Postman. Any ideas?

Comment: could be a few things, such as empty spaces, typo's, wrong format compared to the app's sound. try using other sounds.